# Squish create Auto test suite on application using several jar files

Tags: java, jar, squish

I'm new in the use of Squish Auto Test. I've downloaded Squish Ide for java 5.1 for windows OS. I need to create Automatic Tests scripts for a Java application built on several Jar files. I'm not been able to find enough information on how to create or configure the squish environment, for Automatic Test Suite for application built on several jar files.

Could you help me to solve this problem, please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you will need to give some additional info. The easiest way to begin testing would be if you could compile your program to obtain an installable version.
From what i know, Squish only deals with installable apps, and not with their libraries and so on.

For more details: the development team, can give the cpp files in which they store the code, for my app, but instead, thei are building it, and and provide me whit a installable version, under the form of app.exe, which I'm installing like any other program.

It might be another way: http://doc.froglogic.com/squish/4.1/qt/rg-hooksubattach.html, you can document on it, but I can't recommend it to you, coz' I haven't tried it yet :).